# change an object value on click event

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Trying to change the object rectBox color value on a click event.
Not sure how to do this or what i am doing wrong.
any help would be much appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/z3Ka8/

Here is my code

```
    <div id="pageWrapper">
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
<div class="btnWrapper">
    <button class="buttonClass" id="button1" type="button">BUTTON1</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="button2" type="button">BUTTON2</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="button3" type="button">BUTTON3</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="button4" type="button">BUTTON4</button>
    <button class="buttonClass" id="button5" type="button">BUTTON5</button>
</div>
```

```
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    (function() {

        var color = 'green',

         rectBox = {
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: color,
            borderWidth: 3
        };

        var flavor = ['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'strawberry', 'rootbeer', 'bannana'];
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        function drawrect(rectBox, ctx) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(rectBox.x,rectBox.y,rectBox.width,rectBox.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = rectBox.backgroundColor;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.lineWidth = rectBox.borderWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            ctx.stroke();
        }drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color);

        var btn = $('.buttonClass');
        for(var i=0; i < btn.length; i++) {
            btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            test(e.target.id, rectBox);
          }, false);
        }

        function test(id, rectBox, color) {
            if(id == "button1"){
                console.log(flavor[0]);
                color = 'purple';
            }
            if(id == "button2"){
                console.log(flavor[1]);
                color = 'green';
            }
            if(id == "button3"){
                console.log(flavor[2]);
                color = 'pink';
            }
            if(id == "button4"){
                console.log(flavor[3]);
                color = 'brown';
            }
            if(id == "button5"){
                console.log(flavor[4]);
                color = 'yellow';
            }
        }
    })();
```

Comment: where is "rectBox"??and would be helful if u could create a jsfiddle and state exactly what is the issue?

Comment: you have `function drawrect(rectBox, ctx)` then call it `drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color);` which does not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add another color, then reference that color index instead of the name you can use:

```
(function ($) {

    var color = 2,
        flavor = ['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'strawberry', 'rootbeer', 'bannana'],
        rectBox = {
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: ['purple','yellow', 'green', 'brown', 'pink'],
            borderWidth: 3
        };

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    function drawrect(rectBox, ctx, colorIndex) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(rectBox.x, rectBox.y, rectBox.width, rectBox.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = rectBox.backgroundColor[colorIndex];
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = rectBox.borderWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color);//draw with initial green color

    // use the index of the element (button) in the group
    $('#pageWrapper .btnWrapper').on('click', '.buttonClass', function (e) {
        var myIndex = $(this).index('.buttonClass');
        drawrect(rectBox, ctx, myIndex);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I don't really know what you want to do with the flavor, etc., but this gets the color done.

Updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3Ka8/2/

Comment: how does the colorIndex work? i am a little confused on how you tie it all together if you wouldn't mind explaining a little more, thanks

Comment: myIndex is the index of the button clicked, and it uses that for the color array (select index element in backgroundColor).  "color" is set to 2 for the default index ("green") value. SO colorIndex gets passed either one of those in the function call.

Answer (score 1):

The part which adds the click handler is kinda wrong. btn[i] is actually a jQuery object. It's not a DOM object. So, you should use the *on* method to attach events:

```
for(var i=0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        btn.eq(index).on('click', function() {
            test($(this).attr("id"), rectBox);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Later in test function you should change the value of the RectBox:

```
    function test(id, rectBox, color) {
        if(id == "button1"){
            console.log(flavor[0]);
            drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color = 'purple');
        }
        if(id == "button2"){
            console.log(flavor[1]);
            drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color = 'green');
        }
        if(id == "button3"){
            console.log(flavor[2]);
            rectBox.color = 'pink';
            drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color = 'pink');
        }
        if(id == "button4"){
            console.log(flavor[3]);
            rectBox.color = 'brown';
            drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color = 'brown');
        }
        if(id == "button5"){
            console.log(flavor[4]);
            rectBox.color = 'yellow';
            drawrect(rectBox, ctx, color = 'yellow');                
        }
    }
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/z3Ka8/1/

Comment: Still no luck on getting the color to change when clicking on the buttons. but you helped me out with getting rid of the addEventListener and using the 'on' method.

Comment: I thought that you want to change the attribute of the rectBox object, not a color of some element in the DOM. Is that the case?

Comment: i want to be able to click on the button and depending on what button is pressed change the color of the box to that appropriate color. hope that makes since